# Get main URL part in PHP

Tags: php, url

OK, this is what I'm trying to do (it's quite a quickie actually, but decided to post in case we come up with something smarter... :-))

- Get a URL like : http://www.somedomain.com/subfolder/yet-another-subfolder/final.php?param=2
- Retrieve just this part : http://www.somedomain.com/subfolder/yet-another-subfolder/

That's what I was thinking of :

```
function getMainPart($url)
{
     $parts = explode("/",$url);
     return str_replace(end($parts),"",$url);
}
```

Do you have anything... smarter or better to suggest? Any ideas? (Or anything more universal/directly-supported-by-PHP?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "right" (albeit a lot more long-winded) way to do it:

```
function getMainPart ($url) {
    $parts = parse_url($url);
    if (!isset($parts['scheme'])) {
        return FALSE; // Not a valid, complete URL
    }
    $out = $parts['scheme'].'://';
    if (!empty($parts['user'])) {
        $out .= $parts['user'];
        if (!empty($parts['pass'])) {
            $out .= ':'.$parts['pass'];
        }
        $out .= '@';
    }
    $out .= $parts['host'];
    if (!empty($parts['port'])) {
        $out .= ':'.$parts['port'];
    }
    $out .= $parts['path'] == '/' ? '/' : dirname($parts['path']);
    return $out;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php):

```
<?php
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor';

print_r(parse_url($url));

echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
?>

Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => hostname
    [user] => username
    [pass] => password
    [path] => /path
    [query] => arg=value
    [fragment] => anchor
)
/path
```

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you try this one:

```
$main_path = realpath(dirname(\__FILE__)) . "main_folder/";
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this one can help:

```
echo 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

But this just works for the current file - not for every random URL ;)
for this you should use [parse_url](http://us.php.net/parse_url) like Fluffeh said..

Comment: This works for the URL of the current file, not any random URL.

Comment: You might want to amend you answer then mate :)

Answer (score 1):

You will need the [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function for this.

```
$parts = parse_url($url);
echo $parts['scheme'] ."://". $parts['host'] . $parts['path'];
```

Answer (score 1):

if you`re certain that your main-part is always ending with / this one is some shorter and does not involve array-functions:

```
$url = 'http://www.somedomain.com/subfolder/yet-another-subfolder/final.php?param=2';
function getMainUrlPart($url) {
    return substr($url, 0, strrpos($url, '/')+1);
}
echo getMainUrlPart($url);
```